# If rowCount empty, try again

Tags: php, mysql, loops, if-statement, rowcount

I am running a query from a table whose data gets refreshed (deleted and re-inserted) every 30 seconds.

I want my query (which outputs row count) to detect that the row count is `null` (or zero) and re-run the query. Maximum retries: 5.

And after 5th retries, if it's still zero, I want the row count to print "0".

I know it's a loop but I don't know how to loop it from within the if for row.

```
<?php

$con=mysqli_connect("HOST","USERNAME","PASS","TABLENAME");


$sql="SELECT id FROM candyshop WHERE candy <= 5 AND sugartype ='hard'";

$number = 0; //init count for loop

if ($result=mysqli_query($con,$sql))
{

  $rowcount=mysqli_num_rows($result);  

  printf($rowcount); //print number of rows

  mysqli_free_result($result);

  $number = $number+1; //increment number for loop

}

mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

Comment: Thing that you want is ajax, see documentation here http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: Its not very likely that the value will change if you fire your query 5 times in a row. Can you explain why you think this is necessary?. A better solution would be using transactions when you delete and insert your data. Then the table is never empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a do while loop and only leave the loop if the rowcount is higher than 0 or 5 retries have been reached.

```
<?php

    $sql = "SELECT id FROM candyshop WHERE candy <= 5 AND sugartype ='hard'";
    $count = 0;
    $retry = 5;

    do {

        // Count the rows
        if ($result = mysqli_query($con, $sql)) {
            $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);
        }

        // Wait for 10ms
        if ($count === 0) {
            usleep(10000)
        }

    } while ($count === 0 && --$retry > 0);

    mysqli_close($con);
```

This is however very bad practice, I would recommend looking for another approach. Why would you clear and then refill the table?

Comment: Why do you have 2 dashes before $retry? Ref. --$retry > 0);

Comment: What about: while ($count === 0 && $retry < 6 );

Comment: The dashes decrease the value of `$retry` by one and then check the condition.

Comment: I tried it - if the table is empty, I get no output.

Comment: My snippet doesn't output anything, that is something you will have to add.  But if any rows were found, they will be in the variable `$result` after this code.

Answer (score 1):

Still new to StackOverflow but can you try this?

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("HOST","USERNAME","PASS","TABLENAME");
$sql="SELECT id FROM candyshop WHERE candy <= 5 AND sugartype ='hard'";
$number = 0; //init count for loop
if ($result=mysqli_query($con,$sql)) {
    $rowcount=mysqli_num_rows($result);
    printf($rowcount); //print number of rows
    mysqli_free_result($result);
    $number = $number+1; //increment number for loop
    if ($number = 5) {
        printf(0);
        break 2;
    }
}
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$i = 0;
do {
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
    $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);
} while ($count == 0 && $i++ < 5)
```

Answer (score 0):

As i understood you are trying to write a Web Based Game. Actually your method is probably going to make database a little busy. You don't have to loop queries. If you are going to do it, we are talking about milliseconds here. Let's say your queries are generally giving results in 0.05 seconds that means for 5 query you are just going to have the data of 0.25 seconds.

You can write your game or whatever easily with COMET Programming. But if you decided to go with loop queries , there is only one thing you will do and it's for loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
$rowcount=0;
do {
 if ($result=mysqli_query($con,$sql)) {
  $rowcount=mysqli_num_rows($result);

  printf($rowcount); //print number of rows
  mysqli_free_result($result);

 }
} while(++$number<5 && $rowcount!=0);
```

that is basicaly the answer to your request, though it needs some more explanation to be useful.